# can split column in table to two fields in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a columns -checkin check Out- in `Attendance` table,

I want to split into two  fields(check-In , Checkout) and apply different conditions on them.

Comment: This really needs to be stored at table level as its own column, then it would be easier to just utilise both columns. if you are stuck with the format you are using then you can use the sql console to split the field in 2, by using left(yourcolumnname,12) (or however many chars the date is) as checkin and right(yourcolumnname,12) as checkout. once you have the 2 fields you will then need to convert the value to date so you can apply condtition on them.

Comment: what is the name of your column? is this "checkin check Out". Also give the sample data to understand that it is datetime or only time or else, so we suggested as per that.

Also what you have tried so far. As suggested below, that you can use formula to split, based on your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, just create 2 formulas. 
Each formula splits the db field and uses the relevant part.

**@Formula1**
Split(dbdataField,";")[1]
//Do some work with part #1

**@Formula2**
Split(dbdataField,";")[2]
//Do some work with part #2

To start it, place the DB field and both formulas side by side on details area until you get it right(editing formulas)...it always helps me to see both original and transformed data side by side.

Edit: You can have other formulas using the output of these previous two formulas to make further calculations.